# Any idea why did a return function (false or true) stops the looping?

Tags: php, codeigniter, return

I spent almost a day fixing a bug in my code. After a while I decided to put the code of lines one by one and found what makes the loop function stop working then I figured out that it's when I put a return value inside my if-else statement. Any idea guys? I really need my code to return true or false for my validation.
here's the code before:

```html
 
  $day = $this->input->post('daysched');
   $count = 0; 
    
    foreach ($day as $key => $value) 
    { 
       
            
           

            

        $sched_details = array(
       'sys_id' => $this->input->post('sys_id'),
       'time_in' => $this->input->post('time_in'),
       'time_out' => $this->input->post('time_out'),
       'day' => $value
       );

  $check_details = array(
       'sys_id' => $this->input->post('sys_id'),
       'day' => $value
       );

  $this->db->where($check_details);
  $q = $this->db->get('tbl_worksched');

  if($q->num_rows==0){ 

  $s = $this->db->insert('tbl_worksched', $sched_details); 
  return true;

  }

  else{

  return false;
  }

  $count++; 
         
    } 
    
    return $count;
```

and after I make my code work(after I remove the return in if-else statements):

```html
 $day = $this->input->post('daysched');
  $count = 0; 
    
    foreach ($day as $key => $value) 
    { 
       
        $sched_details = array(
       'sys_id' => $this->input->post('sys_id'),
       'time_in' => $this->input->post('time_in'),
       'time_out' => $this->input->post('time_out'),
       'day' => $value
       );

  $check_details = array(
       'sys_id' => $this->input->post('sys_id'),
       'day' => $value
       );

  $this->db->where($check_details);
  $q = $this->db->get('tbl_worksched');

  if($q->num_rows==0){ 

  $s = $this->db->insert('tbl_worksched', $sched_details); 

  }

  else{

  }

   $count++; 

    } 
    
    return $count; 
  

  
 
 }
```

Comment: Can you put the sample code here?

Comment: If you want help explaining your code, we need to see the actual code or a simple code example of what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1, thats what return does, as if statement is true it finishes function and returns some value

2, you should add code in case you want us to help you (in case there is some other problem than misunderstanding what happens)

Comment: yeah. I sort of understand your point. I just edited my question guys. thanks :D

Comment: yep. I just need to put a return value to run my validation function. :(